# Import problem on react three drei library

Tags: reactjs, package.json, react-three-drei

Hello Everyone I would like to import an item from the react three draie library however I have the following error when importing

I currently have the version of react three drei

```
"@react-three/drei": "^8.20.2",
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkU5y.png)

I would like to know what is the command line to update the library

I thank you for your answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the library package.
Its current version is: v9.32.4

```
npm update @react-three/drei
npm install
```